# get values near to main value in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table **`results`** .

Table has **name** and **amount** columns

There are thousands of records there. Some have in range of hundreds, some are having a range of thousands , some are 100k and some tens of millions.

I get **$amount** as a variable from the url.

I want only 6 results which are closer to **$amount** .

This time I am using **between** clause of mysql . But problem is how will I know that how much I use below or upper to $amount.

Comment: Provide some examples and exact code so we can give proper answers.

Comment: That depends on specific problem. How are you defining 'near to $amount'? Its const value, +- 10%?

Comment: @Kasyx $amount is variable.

Comment: If you want to paginate or select a set within a range, use `LIMIT offset, amount`.

Answer (score 2):

Take the absolute difference, then use `limit` to get the top few:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `numbers` 
ORDER BY ABS( amount - $amount ) ASC 
LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try below query,

```
SELECT name, amount, ABS( amount - $amount ) AS diff
FROM results
ORDER BY diff
LIMIT 6
```